# Ruby on Rails - Finding the Top Three by Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Submission` and `Score` model. Our users can be assigned as judges to score submissions (therefore a submission can have many scores; the `Scores` table has a `submission_id` column, the judge's score of a submission goes in the `total_score` column in the `Score` table).

After finding the final score (by averaging all child total_scores, see below) **I need to calculate which submissions specifically take first, second, and third place.** So far I have this code in the `Submission` model:

```
  def winner?
    winners = Submission.select('submissions.*, AVG(scores.total_score) as avg_score')
    .joins(:scores).group('submissions.id').order('AVG(scores.total_score) DESC')
      if self.scores.average(:total_score) == winners[0].avg_score
        return "First Place"
      elsif self.scores.average(:total_score) == winners[1].avg_score
        return "Second Place"
      elsif self.scores.average(:total_score) == winners[2].avg_score
        return "Third Place"
      else
        return ''
      end
  end
```

I need to insert logic so that it doesn't *just* find a first/second/third place winner out of all submissions generated ever, **it finds multiple first/second/third place winners from each `category_id`.** I can't include `where` code that specifically defines the category ID, e.g. `.where(category_id == 4)` because **I want it to find the winners in all categories** (the number of which varies each year).

Am not sure the best way. Thank you for any help. On Rails 4.

Basically: my above code is doing this (in the submission index page):

```
| id | category_id | final_score |    winner?    |
|------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |           1 |        10.0 |  First Place  |
|  2 |           1 |         6.0 |               |
|  3 |           1 |         7.0 |               |
|  4 |           2 |         8.0 |  Third Place  |
|  5 |           2 |         9.0 |  Second Place |
|  6 |           2 |         5.0 |               |
|  7 |           2 |         3.0 |               |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

When I want it to do this:

```
| id | category_id | final_score |    winner?    |
|------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |           1 |        10.0 |  First Place  |
|  2 |           1 |         6.0 |  Third Place  |
|  3 |           1 |         7.0 |  Second Place |
|  4 |           2 |         8.0 |  Second Place |
|  5 |           2 |         9.0 |  First Place  |
|  6 |           2 |         5.0 |  Third Place  |
|  7 |           2 |         3.0 |               |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

Edit: On request, here are both models Submission and Score:

```
Submission 
----------
category_id
user_id 
organization_id
division_id
contest_year
notes
status
physical_version_received
digital_version_received
disqualify
```

Note, my application needs to break winners down not only by category, but also by contest_year and division_id as well. I felt it best to stick to just category_id right now for this question.

```
Score 
-----
user_id 
submission_id
total_score
comments
disqualify
```

To find the final score of a submission by combining all child total_scores is currently a method in the Submission model:

```
def calculate_final_score
    self.scores.average(:total_score)
  end
```

Comment: Remove 'winner?' attribute from Submission entity. It a boolean state already implicitly represented with the 'final_score' attribute.

Comment: Ideally I want the system to explicitly state the winners, not implicitly through final_score (if this is possible).

Comment: Explicitly stating the winners is what you do in your Controller. Maintaining state is what your Model layer does. You can have both, because ActiveRecord lets you, but it is redundant. I understand this isn't an answer, that is why this is a comment.

Comment: That's fine--I didn't think my code was the best way, that's just the first thing that halfway worked! If there is a better way in the controller I would love to know or see a similar example.

Comment: Update your question with attributes for both entities Score and Submission and I'll try to decipher your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
winners=Array.new
Category.all.each do |category|
    winners[category.id]=category.submissions.order(:final_score => :desc).limit(3).map(&:user_id)
end
```

And this would be an array of arrays with the winners per category

Comment: I inserted this into my def winner? in my Submission model and it is returning the error "undefined method `each' for #<Class:0x7bbd870>", not sure why? Also, would this work if I wanted to further break the winners down by category_id, contest_year, and division_id? (I do)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    Score.select('category_id, total_score as final_score, dense_rank() over (partition by total_score) as rank').joins(:submission).group('category_id')
```

This returns you:

```
| category_id | final_score |    rank       |
|-------------------------------------------|
|           1 |        10.0 |             1 |
|           1 |         6.0 |             3 |
|           1 |         7.0 |             2 |
|           2 |         8.0 |             2 |
|           2 |         9.0 |             1 |
|           2 |         5.0 |             3 |
|           2 |         3.0 |             4 |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

With that you can do what you want... for example, you could apply a switch case on sql or a decode... to trade 1, 2, 3... for First, Second, Third...

Obs.: I used Postgre's sintax for window-functions ... you can see more about that kind of queries on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-window.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/tutorial-window.html

But that kind of sorceries there are in many others databases... only the sintax changes.

Ps.: You can use any calculated value on PARTITION BY, here it is used just to order your rank... so, you can alter the ordering (default is DESC)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about dense_rank(). Have a couple of questions. I'm not sure where final_score is coming from, that's just the name I gave the column in my example. I calculated AVG of all scores using my calculate_final_scores method, how does your code take that into account? Secondly, I am not sure I am inserting this right, I am putting this in my Submission model under def winner? but it returns #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Score:0x86bdd30> in the row. Last, would this work if I wanted to further break winners down by category_id, division_id, and contest_year?

Comment: You can use it on winner? iterating and discovering the rank of each submission, but I was not considering it.

final_score you can calculate with avg(total_score), or sum(total_score), I just didn't only to make my example easier...

I did not tested that, I only wrote the query... I just used the sintax, the focus was show you that you can use the window function dense_rank() over (partition by ...)

that technique already do what I thought you wanted... that was identify the classification of each submission grouped by her group

I forgot to put the group by as well... but it is category_id

Comment: I feel like this answer is very close to what I need, I'm just...not sure how to insert it properly. I've been searching around online for other examples of dense_rank() but am coming up with little. So it is not recommended to use this in the Submission index page?

Comment: Well... I thought that you need to rank the categories, and could exist a bunch of submissions on the same category... at least, my example are based on that... 
I think that makes more sense place the rank on ScoreController#index... because the Score has submissions... and so, it would be the better place to rank the submissions.

But, i really don't know exactly the context which you need do that. i just showed you the possibilities to discover the rank in a easier way using a query with window function.
You can see more examples on http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/20-Window-Functions

Comment: Thank you again for all your help. You're right, I need to rank the submissions according to their final averaged score, and broken down by category. But it's the opposite, one submission has many scores. Scores belong to submissions. I will take a look at the link you have provided.